# Dropping the lowest grade from a 2D array and putting the remaining into a new 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, double

I have a 2D array of students, each with 4 grades. I've established a way to find the lowest grade of each student, but I now need to remove the lowest and put the remaining grades into a new array.

The code that I currently have repeats values for each grade and is not accurate. Also, if a student has two lowest grades (i.e 64.3 and 64.3) how could we only remove one?

```java
double studentGrades[][] = {
        {100.0, 98.8, 78.9, 90.3},
        {76.6, 90.8, 78.9, 78.3},
        {78.7, 78.7, 91.2, 100.0},
        {65.9, 94.2, 81.6, 93.6},
        {78.7, 100.0, 93.2, 76.7}};

double temp = 0;
double lowest = 0;

double finalGrades[][] = new double[5][3];

for (int row = 0; row < studentGrades.length; row++) {
    lowest = studentGrades[row][0];
    for (int s = 0; s < studentGrades[0].length; s++) {
        temp = studentGrades[row][s];
        if (lowest > temp) {
            lowest = temp;
        } else {
            for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++) {
                finalGrades[row][m] = studentGrades[row][s];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, the finalGrades array would be set as such:

```
{100.0, 98.8, 90.3},
{90.8, 78.9, 78.3},
{78.7, 91.2, 100.0},
{94.2, 81.6, 93.6},
{78.7, 100.0, 93.2}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```java
for (int row = 0; row < studentGrades.length; row++) {
    int lowest_index = 0;
    for (int s = 1; s < studentGrades[0].length; s++) {
        if (studentGrades[row][s] < studentGrades[row][lowest_index]) {
            lowest_index = s;
        }
    }
    int m = 0;
    for (int s = 0; s < studentGrades[0].length; s++) {
        if (s != lowest_index) {
            finalGrades[row][m] = studentGrades[row][s];
            m++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked for most of them, however it set one of the grades in finalGrades to 0 for a couple students.

Comment: Please update the code . inner loop should start from 0 and not 1. It will work fine then